# 0 Rich Cards but 1k+ Structured Data

Tags: google-search-console, rich-snippets, google-rich-snippets-tool

I have a WordPress multisite network. The three sites have content in WooCommerce, Directory Listing, Q&A, hundreds of posts etc. I am using Yoast SEO plugin. My site is working from last 6 months and it's properly indexed by Google.

In structured data test, I am getting 1000+ results but my Rich Cards is empty. I ran Structured Data Test and did not find any noticeable error.

Why I am not getting anything in Rich Cards?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google only support Rich Cards for movies and recipes (and local restaurants now). It does not appear that any of your content relates to these. You may be confusing Rich Cards with Rich Snippets? Rich Snippets are not included in this report (you may be able to view these in the 'rich result' filter in Search Analytics report, although this not not explicitly say which type of rich snippet was generated).